# Error: Bad math evironment delimiter

Tags: math-mode

I am getting an Error: Bad math evironment delimiter for the following lines:`

```
\[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} i z_{i}\equiv 0\)\ \textrm{mod}\ 11
\]
```

and

```
\[ z_{1} \equiv -  \(\sum \limits_{i=2}^{10} i z_{i}\)\ \textrm{mod}\ 11 0\leq z_{1}\leq 10 
\]
```

The output is shown correctly[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have `\(` and `\)` terms, which serve to initiate and terminate an inline-style equation, inside a display-style math environment. That's what's giving you the "Bad math environment delimiter" error.

I'm not entirely sure, but I'm guessing you want to enclose the summation terms in large parentheses. If that's the case, I suggest you use `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` around the terms. Also, do use `\mod` (from the `amsmath` package) instead of `\ \textrm{mod}\`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\mod" macro
\begin{document}
\[ 
\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{10} i z_{i}\equiv 0\biggr) \mod 11
\]
and 
\[ 
z_{1} \equiv -\biggl(\,\sum_{i=2}^{10} i z_{i}\biggr) \mod 11 0\leq z_{1}\leq 10 
\]
\end{document}
```